# Run python script and output to txt for a list of URLs

Tags: python

I have a python script for **scraping** some URLs. The URLs are in a list in a txt file.

The python script (only relevant parts) are as follows:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'https://www.example.com/post/1245'

# rest of the code is here

print quote_page
print url
print title
print description
print actors
print director
```

I would like to run this script for multiple URLs in a txt file and output to a single txt file.

Any ideas how I can run this for my URLs in txt file?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to use the Python [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement (introduced in [PEP 343](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html)) and the built-in [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function:

```
# Python 2
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

# Python 3
# import urllib3
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Python 2.6+ and Python 3
with open('urls.txt','r') as url_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:

    url_list = url_file.readlines()

    for url_item in url_list:

        # quote_page = 'https://www.example.com/post/1245'
        quote_page = url_item

        # rest of the code is here

        # Python 2 and 3
        output_file.write(quote_page)
        output_file.write(url)
        output_file.write(title)
        output_file.write(description)
        output_file.write(actors)
        output_file.write(director)
        output_file.write('\n')
```

In this instance, we:

1. `open()` file handles (`url_file`,`output_file`) to our input and output text files (`'urls.txt'`,`'output.txt'`) at the same time (using `'r'` for reading and `'w'` for writing, respectively).
2. Use the `with` statement to close these files automatically after we are done fully processing our URLs. Normally, we would need to issue separate e.g. `url_file.close()` and `output_file.close()` commands (ex. at Step 5).
3. Put our URLs into a list (`url_list = url_file.readlines()`).
4. Loop through our URL list and `write()` the data we want to our `output_file`.
5. `close()` both of our files automatically (see Step 2).

Note that to simply add data to an existing `output_file`, you will probably wish to use `'a'` (append mode) rather than `'w'` (write mode). So e.g. `open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file` would become `open('output.txt', 'a') as output_file`. This is important because `'w'` (write mode) will truncate the file if the file already exists (i.e. you will lose your original data).